# Remove &nbsp; at the beginning of the_excerpt() with str_replace

Tags: php, excerpt

I am trying to remove blank spaces at the beginning of the_excerpt();. They are cuased by blanc spaces between two images in the content. I have unsuccessfully tried to get rid of them by using str_replace, in the code below.

```
$string = get_the_excerpt();
$string = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$string);
echo $string;
```

With the same setup it is possible to remove normal spacing

```
$string = get_the_excerpt();
$string = str_replace(' ','',$string);
echo $string;
```

Why is this and how may I remove the `&nbsp;`?

**UPDATE**

This is how the images are placed in the editor - it is the space between the images causing the `&nbsp;` at the beginning of the excerpt.
[image: This is how the images are placed in the editor - it is the space between the images causing the at the beginning of the excerpt. .]

This is the result

[image: This is the result]

This is what it looks like when I inspect the elements.
[image: This is what it looks like when I inspect the elements.]

Comment: This is more a php question in general than wp specific.

Comment: Why not to just write an excerpt instead of fighting one bug at a time?

Comment: Yes perhaps @cjbj but it is working fine with a regular string as in examples but not when I retrieve the excerpt? Because it will be a reoccurring problem @MarkKaplun!

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to remove characters at the begining of a string.

```
$str = '&nbsp;&nbsp;      Some Stuff here   this is ok and &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; this is';

echo ltrim(ltrim($str, '&nbsp;'), ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this works with your example but not with the excerpt.. @jgraup

Comment: Can you paste the full string so it's possible to test with your data?

Comment: I have updated with some images to explain how I set up the string @jgraup

Comment: I see, so it's a mix until you hit a non-space char. Easy enough but I won't have time today to update this.

Comment: Actually, just replace 'nsbsp' with ' ' before l trim. Normalizing it will help.

Comment: It is still not working unfortunately :( @jgraup thank you for trying!