# Remove &nbsp from the_excerpt

Tags: php, html, excerpt

Wordpress is creating a &nbsp in the_excerpt. How do I remove it?

```
<div class="subtitulo-noticia"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
```

[image]

&nbsp creates a space at the beginning of p

[image]

Edit: Each space in the_content creates a &nbsp, this ends up creating a &nbsp in the_excerpt. How do I create spaces in content without creating &nbsp

Comment: looks to me like you need to edit the excerpt itself in the wp-admin, it looks like you have some spaces preceding the content.

Comment: What exactly do I need to edit?

Comment: the post itself. you need to edit the content typed into the post editor. and remove the leading spaces with the `delete` key

Comment: maybe take a look here, if there are images in your post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229679/remove-nbsp-at-the-beginning-of-the-excerpt-with-str-replace?rq=1

Comment: Each space in the content creates a &nbsp, but how do I make a space without creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why there's a non-breaking space being added to the front of your excerpt. It would be best to find out what is putting that there. But in the meantime, you can add this to your theme functions.php ( or a simple plugin ) and it should take care of it.

```
//* Remove non-breaking space from beginning of paragraph
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', function( $excerpt ) {
  return str_replace( [ '<p>&nbsp; ', '<p>&nbsp;' ], '<p>', $excerpt );
}, 999, 1 );
```

Comment: This just shows one ; In front of the text

Comment: Oops. That was a typo. Sorry. Fixed it - notice the ; after the &nbsp now.

Comment: Now it will remove the space after the non-breaking space as well if it's present.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get rid of the extra space in the admin, then use trim()

```
<div class="subtitulo-noticia"><?php echo trim(get_the_excerpt()); ?></div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

Comment: Did not work, do I need to add something in functions.php?

Comment: try `trim(get_the_excerpt(), '&nbsp');`  Really you should be able to remove that from the post/page editor.  That extra space exists somewhere and is causing that `&nbsp` to show up.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work either

Comment: vardump get_the_excerpt() and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$text = str_replace( "&nbsp","",get_the_excerpt() );
```

Maybe, replacing `&nbsp` with an empty string could be fix your problem.
The `get_the_excerpt()` function will get your post's excerpt and [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) substitute `&nbsp`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

```
<?php echo trim(preg_replace('/>\s+</m', '><', get_the_content()));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a modified version of Nathan's solution to resolve the issue of WordPress adding in extra empty heading and space tags. While not comprehensive, it does save me from editing 200+ pages in the CMS to bring them up to accessibility level compliance. Also, we know that even if we fix the 200+ pages someone will do it again, so it would become a reoccurring issue to resolve.

```php
// Remove non-breaking space from beginning of paragraph
add_filter( 'the_content', function ( $content ) {
    $search = [
        '<h1></h1>', 
        '<h2></h2>', 
        '<h3></h3>', 
        '<h4></h4>', 
        '<h5></h5>', 
        '<h6></h6>', 
        '<p></p>', 
        '<span></span>', 
        '&nbsp;',
    ];

    return str_replace( $search, '', $content );
}, 999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code into your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', function( $excerpt ) {
  return str_replace( '&nbsp;', '', $excerpt );
}, 999, 1);
```